# Determine all values of $z$ (if any) where $\,f (z)= \cos(|z|^2)$ is analytic?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

ok , I proceeded with the Cauchy riemann equations , setting $\,z = x + iy$ and so $\,f(z) = \cos(x^2+y^2)$ and then did $\,f(z) = u(x,y) + iv(x,y)$  where $u(x,y) = \cos(x^2 + y^2)$  and $v(x,y) = 0$ , until i got that inorder to be analytic at any point it must satisfy these pair of equations  $\,-2x \sin(x^2+y^2) = 0$ and $-2y \sin(x^2+y^2) = 0$ and so now I don't know which points the function is analytic

Comment: Notice $x^2+y^2\in\mathbb{R}$ so these are our familiar trigonometric functions $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$. Clearly either $x=0$ and $y=0$ work, as does $x^2+y^2=\pi n,n\in\mathbb{Z}$. These are points where $f$ is complex differentiable.

Comment: There's a difference between complex differentiable and analytic. $f$ being analytic in $z$ means $f$ is represented by a power series in a neighbourhood of $z$. The given $f$ is analytic nowhere. But it is complex differentiable in a few points.

Answer (score 1):

By the open mapping theorem, an analytic function maps an open set to an open set (in the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$).   But $\cos|z|^2)$ is real, and the real line is not an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$.  So you can see at a glance that this is nowhere analytic.